# Nesting HTML5 section tags

Tags: html

Is this a correct way to use the `<section>` tag?

```
<section id="container">
   <section id="outer">
      <section id="inner">
      </section>
   </section>
</section>
```

I'm trying to work out whether or not I should use only one section id, and leave the other two sections as just divs?

Comment: HTML5 spec on the [section element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-section-element).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you are just using these elements to place things in some position / style things, then you should probably be using divs.

Section is really for grouping content that belongs together - you shouldn't really have a section without a title (H1 or similar) element describing what the section contains... a few people have made similar mistakes in the past I think:

http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

From the spec:

> **NOTE:** The section element is not a generic container element. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.

Having said that, it's perfectly acceptable to nest section elements. Maybe something like:

```
<section>
    <h1>Portishead</h1>
    <p>Portishead are a cool band from Bristol</p>
    <section>
        <h1>Dummy (album)</h1>
        <p>some info....</p>
        <img src="..." />
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Portishead (album)</h1>
        <p>some other info info....</p>
        <img src="..." />
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: would you mind linking that quote from w3c? Typically "headers" and "footers" are marked up with `header` and `footer` elements respectively.

Comment: @zzzzBov - no problem (Does seem a bit weird considering the header / footer tags, eh?)

Comment: just as i suspected. w3schools is ***in no way affiliated*** with the w3c. Please read through [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: Would you still use a section as the parent if you only had the h1 and no p there. That's my dilema.

Comment: this example isn't really all that great, as it misuses nested `<section>` where it really should be using `<ul>`. This would (have) be(en) better: `<section><h1>portishead></h1><section><h2>biography</h2>...</section><section><h2>discography</h2><ul>...</ul></section>`.

Comment: Good answer, but don't use more than one H1 per page, the other header tags here should be H2's or H3's, depending on the other content of this fictional page.

Comment: Just voted this up because it is a good answer and because Portishead is really good music.

Comment: The header level should probably represent the section level. Only one h1 per page

Comment: would grouping a group of images, whereby each image in the group corresponds to, say, an `article` in a group of `articles` elsewhere in the document, in a `section` element be considered an appropriate usage of the `section` element?

Answer (score 11):

> **Note:**
>
> My answer is severely out-of-date, and no longer contains sound advice given the changes to HTML that have happened in the last decade. I will be leaving this answer as-is for historical context, but please be aware that the structure suggested is not best practice—particularly around the use of the obsolete [document outline](http://html5doctor.com/computer-says-no-to-html5-document-outline/).

Short answer: The code as you've provided is not semantically valid.

Long answer:

`section` elements are meant to mark up *sections* of content. Each section of content (i.e. Introduction, Abstract, content, conclusion) could have subsections.

If you're using those elements for structural purpose, you should be using `div` elements instead. They are semantically meaningless.

This would be more semantic:

```
<section id="introduction">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      Some content
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This would be a semantic way of marking up nested sections:

```
<section id="content">
  <h1>Fizz Buzz</h1>
  <section id="chapter-1">
    <h1>Foo bar baz</h1>
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="chapter-2">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    ...
  </section>
  ....
</section>
```

Comment: Although this is only a skeletal example, it does look like the first section tag is being used as a container, surely a div would be used if the direct children are sections.

Comment: @Neil, I suppose I did leave out adding a heading to `#content`

Comment: First tag is okey, it is not only a container used for styling. But  I see other issue here:  It is not good idea (especially in SEO context) to have multiple h1 tags, and also header of nested section should have next "h" tag. For example h2 for content and h3 for chapters.

Comment: @jazzgot, [please read the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#headings-and-sections).

Comment: @zzzzBov Ok, you have right with multiple `<h1>` tags (nesting headings still should be from h1 to h6). But can't you write in more usefull way? If someone will look at your comment, he probably don't find what was wrong in my thinking. [Here is usefull article about using multiple `<h1>` tags on page.](http://example.com)

Comment: @jazzgot, if you feel that my answer is lacking, by all means add your own. Comments are not the place for extended discussion.

Comment: note that the `<section id="content">` is misleading: if this was really the element wrapping all "real" page content, that should have been `<main>`, not `<section>`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, while I suppose I have made a couple superficial edits since posting this most of a decade ago, I haven't made any significant changes. At the time of writing [the `<main>` element didn't exist](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/), and wasn't introduced for another two years ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)). That's to say, I wouldn't consider this post misleading _per se_, so much as **drastically out of date**. As I don't have time for a rewrite, I'll add a note for now.

Comment: That's fair - given that folks will still find it rather high in Google if they search for "nested section", that's a worthwhile edit.

Answer (score 3):

My personal recommendation would be to utilize semantic structure as much as possible when you create HTML5 layouts. **As other posters have indicated, nesting section elements is totally acceptable**, however you need to just make sure it makes sense to do so.

I personally use a few patterns that I've put together based on some research I've done over the course of the last year or so. The most common situation for using nested section elements is to provide ARIA roles for the main content of the document (see "site layout" example below)

*Note: assumes body/html elements are present, etc*

**Site Layout**

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
  ....
</header>

<!-- used once per page, implies role="main" -->   
<main> 
  <!-- declares page content to be a document and not a web app -->
  <section id="wrapper" role="document"> 

   <section class="hero">
      ....
   </section>
      ....
   <section class="content">

   </section>

  </section>
</main>

<footer class="footer" role="footer">

      ....

</footer>
```

**Single-Page Content Layout**

*Note: This layout applies to a page with a singular/topic/object and isn't suitable for all use cases*

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Page Headline/Title</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="page-content">
      ....
  </section>
  <!-- if this is a post or something with metadata/authorship info... -->
  <footer>
    ....
  </footer>
</article>
```

I use the tag for the class name on the shell header/footer elements as well as landmark roles to insure I can always distinguish them from other header/footer elements within the page (e.g. easy CSS scoping).

**References**

- role="document" https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#document

  > A region containing related information that is declared as document content, as opposed to a web application.
- "Why the `<main>` element doesn't need a role attribute": https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-main-element-20121217/

  > The main element formalises the common practice of identification of the main content section of a document using the id values such as 'content' and 'main'. It also defines an HTML element that embodies the semantics and function of the WAI-ARIA landmark role=main.
- "W3.org/Wiki explanation of nesting `<section>` elements" - https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_section_element

  > The section element is a container for document content that has a related theme, and represents the section of a document that is grouped around a general concept. Everything within a section element is related. **Also section elements may be nested if necessary**. The section element is a generic semantic element, that can be used to combine portions of a document together into discrete units that are related in some way. For example, the section element may create items inside an outline of a document, or divide page content into related pieces (like an Introduction) followed by some background information on the topic.

Comment: Good lord this question is old. Either way, I hope the info I provided is helpful to someone else who searches this topic.

Comment: Note that `<main><section role="document">...</section></main>` makes very little sense: that section element literally does nothing semantic, and this should have just been `<main>`. Also `role="document"` is far more specific than this answer claims, and in this case does nothing because pages are documents by default, you use `role="document"` when you need to break out of non-document mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Document_Role

Answer (score 3):

A useful way to think through this is to consider how a screen reader would see your site. Imagine (and in fact you should test this for yourself) the screenreader announcing the word 'section' before reading the content inside your `<section>` tag.

If that doesn't make logical sense then maybe you've got your items ordered wrong.

Check out [aria region role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Region_role).

I don't know exactly how screen readers read nested sections but if the logical
sections on your page don't have a hierarchy then your HTML shouldn't either.

eg. (this is meant to represent HTML structure)

**GOOD**

```
section aria-label="dogs"
   section aria-label="labradors"
   section aria-labels="terriers"

section aria-label="cats"
   section aria-label="sphynx"
   section aria-label="persian"
```

**BAD**

Section used solely to group two other sections, but without a real meaning of its own as a 'section'.

```
section style="display: flex; flex-direction: row"
   section aria-label="news"
   section aria-labels="sport"
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 also allows for setups such as:

```
<section>

<header>Header of section</header>
<aside><ul><li></li></ul></aside><!-- previously known as sidebar -->
<footer>Footer of section</footer>

</section>
```

multiple times on the same page, so you don't have just the one header, it goes a lot deeper than this, but it's worth checking out.

Check out the http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Comment: [that's not what the aside element is for](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-aside-element).

Answer (score 0):

An updated method (as far as I understand it) could be something like this:

```
<main id="content">
  <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <section>
      <h1>Section Title</h1>
      ...
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Section Title</h1>
      ...
    </section>
  </div>
</main>

main {
  width: 100%;
  ...
  ...
}

#inner_wrapper {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-main-element/, http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-main-element/ or http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/ for more info.